# Automatically change numeration in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel Worksheet and the column A should be automatically numerized between A4 and ~A50 (depends on how many clients there are, but normally it's around 41 - 43, maximum 45) when I add a new row.

For example: A4 has the value 1, A5 has 2, A6 has 3, etc. until A43 which has the value 40. I want to add a new row somewhere in between and the numbers should change accordingly... Also, the number of total clients has increased, so the cell A44 shoud now hold the new number 41.

I searched Google and found out, that I had to write a VB macro for that (is that true, can't that be solved in an easier way? Excel is so mighty powerful, but it can't do that?) and it works somewhat. However, when I do try to add a new row, it doesn't behave correctly, the numbers at the end of the table get messed up a bit and it doesn't count correctly:

[image: Excel numeration problem]

It's always in the same area, the number 38 doesn't switch to 39. Unfortunately, my VB skills are very limited, and they already were 5 years ago, when I last used it. Here's the script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cntClients As Integer
    Dim lastCell As Integer
    Dim startNum As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer

    cntClients = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A4:A60"))
    lastCell = cntClients + 3
    startNum = 1
    startRow = 4

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Do While startRow <= cntClients
        Range("A" & startRow).Value = startNum
        startRow = startRow + 1
        startNum = startNum + 1
    Loop
    Range("A" & lastCell) = cntClients
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I hope I got my point accross clearly and if there's an easier solution for this problem, one that potentially does not use macros, please let me know!

If you need any further information, I'll gladly provide them!

EDIT: Also, when I delete the newly added row, the numbers don't change correctly either, like here:

[image: Excel problem 2]

Somehow the macro does not like the number 39

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are compensating for the start at row 4 with `lastCell = cntClients + 3` but then never using the compensated value.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cntClients As Integer
    Dim lastCell As Integer
    Dim startNum As Integer
    Dim startRow As Integer

    cntClients = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A4:A60"))
    lastCell = cntClients + 3
    startNum = 1
    startRow = 4

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Do While startRow <= lastCell   'cntClients   <~~ this. not that.
        Range("A" & startRow).Value = startNum
        startRow = startRow + 1
        startNum = startNum + 1
    Loop

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I've also removed an unnecessary line which had the same problem.

Comment: Thank. you. so much! Works perfectly! I was blind to see that after an hour of tinkering my way around the problem

Answer (score 2):

Without VBA:

If you turn your data table into a `TABLE` (you can use the `Insert/Table` method), you can then use a formula such as

```
A4:  =ROW()-3
```

and fill down.

When you subsequently insert or delete rows, the formula will propagate and the numbers will adjust properly.

Comment: Thank you! Next time I'll probably solve it that way. Seems much easier

Comment: @PatrickManser Tables are powerful.  And if you have formulas in other columns, they will automatically propagate also.

Answer (score 0):

Use AGGREGATE function(excel2010 and upper):

Array form
AGGREGATE(function_num, options, array, [k])

```
=AGGREGATE(4,5,$A$1:A1)+1

function_num --   4 (MAX)
options      --   5 (Ignore hidden rows)
```